# Imported unique constraints doesn't get validated

Tags: spring, grails, constraints

I have a Spring Security User class which has a unique constraint for username and email. In a Command class I imported all constraints from this class with "importFrom User". All constraints work as expected EXCEPT the unique ones.

However when saving the User the unique constraints get validated and errors are shown. But it would be nice if they get validated BEFORE saving like all other constraints.

**UPDATE**

I added this to the controller:

```
user.errors.fieldErrors.each {
    command.errors.rejectValue(it.getField(), it.getCode())
}
```

Seems like a dirty workaround, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Good question @Chris, and your solution is best since the goal of sharing constraints between domain classes and command objects is to avoid duplicating validation logic.

I'll just add that to avoid duplicating field errors and to handle nested field paths in domain objects, something like the following might be necessary.

```
def save(EntityCreateCommand cmd) {
    def entity = new Entity(cmd.properties)
    def someAssociation = new Something(cmd.properties)
    entity.someAssociation = someAssociation

    entity.validate()

    entity.errors.fieldErrors.each {
        def fieldName = it.field.split("\\.").last()
        def flattenedCodes = cmd.errors.getFieldErrors(fieldName).codes.flatten()
        if(cmd.hasProperty(fieldName) && (!flattenedCodes.contains(it.code))) {
            cmd.errors.rejectValue(fieldName, 
                "entityCreateCommand.${fieldName}.${it.code}")
        }
    }

    if(cmd.errors.hasErrors()) {
        error handling stuff...
    } else {
        business stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with unique constraint before, so I made a custom validator in my command object to test and see if it's unique:

Command Object:

```
class wateverCommand{
    ....
    String username

    static constraints = {
        username validator:{value, command ->
            if(value){
                 if(User.findByUsername(value){
                     return 'wateverCommand.username.unique'
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

within your messages.properties add a custom error message:

```
wateverCommand.username.unique The username is taken, please pick a new username
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree the unique constraint doesn't always seem to import properly.  Since I like to avoid clutter in the constraint body I like the one liner approach:

```
validator: {value, command ->  (User.findByUsername(value) ? false : true ) }
```

Then in your message.properties it would be:

```
accountCommand.username.validator.error=That username already exists
```